# Is there a way to split a string into length n but also accounting for its permutations?

Tags: python, slice

permutations might not be exactly the right word.

say `x = "123456"`.
I want my code to output `['12','23','34','45','56']`.
Right now, I know how to split it into `['12','34','56']`

Comment: Share the code that you use please

Comment: `res = [a+b  for a, b in zip(list(x), list(x)[1:])]`

Comment: Similar: [Splitting a Python list into a list of overlapping chunks](/q/36586897/4518341). (It says list, but it works for any sequence, including strings.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a range that increments by 1

```
def split_into(values, n):
    return [values[i:i + n] for i in range(len(values) - n + 1)]


x = "123456789"
print(split_into(x, 2))  # ['12', '23', '34', '45', '56', '67', '78', '89']
print(split_into(x, 3))  # ['123', '234', '345', '456', '567', '678', '789']
print(split_into(x, 4))  # ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
print(split_into(x, 5))  # ['12345', '23456', '34567', '45678', '56789']
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much, I tried incrementing it by 1 by forgot that I should subtract n+1 from the length.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10, it looks like [`itertools.pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) will do what you want:

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> print(*map(''.join, pairwise("123456")))
```

The above is just a simulation as I don't have 3.10 yet ;-)  Until then, the documenation for `pairwise()` provides an alternative:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

print(*map(''.join, pairwise("123456")))
```

Comment: It's close. `pairwise()` returns 2-tuples, not slices. This works: `list(map(''.join, pairwise(x)))`

Comment: Beside the point, but you know you can install 3.10 on any OS, right? You can also try it out [on Python.org](https://www.python.org/shell/).